# HELP : Complex Analysis exercise

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ such that $$f(z)=\sqrt{|z|}\cdot\left(\cos\left({\frac{\arg z}{2}}\right) + i\cdot\sin\left({\frac{\arg z}{2}}\right)\right)$$ if $z$ $\neq$ $0$ and $f(0)=0$.

I have to obtain the same function 
expressed as $f(x+yi)=a(x,y)+b(x,y)i$ where $a$, $b$ : $\mathbb{R}^2$$\longrightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ can´t own **trigonometric expressions on their final expressions**. Moreover, I don't have to use **cases study**. My teacher told me that we can achieve this result using the ***sign function*** and the ***floor and ceiling functions*** but I don't have idea about how to get the result on this way.
I would be grateful if someone could help me to get the result in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say $z= |z|e^{i\theta}$. The expression you have given is clearly $\sqrt {|z|} e^{i\theta\over 2}$, or, $\sqrt z$. So, we have $f(z)^2 = z$, so:
$$(a+bi)^2=x+iy$$
$$a^2-b^2 + i(2ab) = x+iy$$
$$2ab = y, a^2-b^2 = x$$

Solving this system will give you your solution. It may be done as follows:

$$4a^4 - 4a^2x -y^2 = 0$$

$$a^2 = {x\pm\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\over 2}$$ We discard $-$ as $a$ is real and so its square cannot be negative.

$$b = \frac y{2a}$$ $$b = {y\over2\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\over 2}}$$ Simplifying the expression by multiplying and dividing the surd by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x$ we get our solution, which is

$$a(x,y) = \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\over 2}$$
$$b(x,y) = sgn(y)\sqrt{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\over 2}$$

Also note that if $(a,b)$ is a solution, so is $(-a,-b)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$z=x+iy = \sqrt{(x^2+y^2)} \exp[i \tan^{-1}(y/x)] \Rightarrow f(z)=z^{1/2}= (x^2+y^2)^{1/4}~ [ \cos (\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(y/x)) + i \sin  (\frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1}(y/x))]= a(x,y)+ i b(x,y)$$ $$ \Rightarrow a(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)^{1/4} ~ \cos (\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(y/x)), ~~b(x,y) = (x^2+y^2)^{1/4} ~ \sin (\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(y/x)). $$ 
Let $$\tan t=y/x \Rightarrow cos (t/2)=\frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{\sqrt{2}(x^2+y^2)^{1/4}}, \sin (t/2) =\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x}}{\sqrt{2}(x^2+y^2)^{1/4}}$$

Comment: By this way, $a$ and $b$ own trigonometric expressions on their final expressions.

Comment: @ user709118, yes you are right , see my edit.